# Is this loop O(nlog(n))?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I have a nested for loop that I am trying to analyze the efficiency of. The loop looks like this:

```
int n = 1000;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
}
```

I don't believe that this algorithm is O(n^2) because the inner loop does not run n times, it only runs i times. However, it certainly is not O(n). So I hypothesize that it must be between the two efficiencies, which gives O(nlog(n)). Is this accurate or is it really a O(n^2) algorithm and I'm misunderstanding the effect the inner loop has on the efficiency?

Comment: Have a look at the selection sort algorithm and the analysis of its time complexity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your algorithm will run a [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) of times:

> n * (n + 1) / 2

In the above case, `n = 999` because the first `j` loop doesn't run:

> (999 * 1000) / 2 = 499500

It is lower than `n**2`, but it still is `O(n**2)`, because `n * (n + 1) / 2` is `n**2 / 2 + n / 2`. When `n` is large, you can ignore `n / 2` compared to `n**2 / 2`, and you can also ignore the constant `1 / 2` factor.

Comment: I hadn't made the connection to Gauss's summation formula. That makes it much clearer.

Answer (score 2):

I kind of get your doubts, but try to think in this way: what value will `i` have in the worst case scenario? Answer is `n-1`, right? So, as the complexity is evaluated by considering the worst case scenario it turns out that it is `O(n^2)` as `n * (n-1) ~ n^2`.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The number of iterations is `sum from i=0 to n-1 (sum from j=0 to i-1 (1))`. The inner sum is obviously equal to `i`. `sum from i=0 to n-1 (i) = n * (n-1) / 2 = O(n^2)` is well known.